# Motion vs space expansion

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, observers

Let us consider two particles A and B in empty space, and let us assume that I am an observer attached to particle A. Also let us assume that, according to my measurements, I see that the distance from particle A to particle B increases over time.

According to General relativity, this could happen in two ways:

1. The two particles are moving through space
2. The two particles are still in space, but the space itself is expanding

If all information I have is how the distance between A and B increases with respect to proper time measured in A, how can I tell in which scenario I am?

Comment: Point one should be "particle B move in space".

Comment: Are the bodies free falling? Or are you admitting  that there are non gravitational forces acting on them?

Comment: @ValterMoretti: Well, actually I am considering the problem from a purely cinematic point of view: in Newtonian mechanics every observer can be considered standing still, he/she will describe the trajectory of other bodies in different ways. However, the relative motion between two bodies, i.e. how their distance changes over time is an invariant on which all observer agree. In special relativity, one can still define two particles standing still with respect to each other if their wordlines are two parallel straightlines. However, how does the situation change in General relativity?

Comment: The point is that, in spacetime, the spatial distance is not a well defined notion, if you do not fix some preferred structure that embodies the worldlines as preferred curves. The typical situation is a comoving reference frame of FLRW spacetimes where the worldlines are Comoving free falling bodies.

Answer (score 3):

> Motion vs space expansion

The two body situation cannot separated the two hypothesis you offer. Either can be assumed. Actually in order to establish with data that the [space in our universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe) is expanding, astrophysicists needed data from the galaxies all around the earth

> [In 1912, Vesto Slipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe#History) discovered that light from remote galaxies was redshifted. which was later interpreted as galaxies receding from the Earth. In 1922, Alexander Friedmann used Einstein field equations to provide theoretical evidence that the universe is expanding. In 1927, Georges Lemaître independently reached a similar conclusion to Friedmann on a theoretical basis, and also presented the first observational evidence for a linear relationship between distance to galaxies and their recessional velocity. Edwin Hubble observationally confirmed Lemaître's findings two years later.Assuming the [cosmological principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_principle), these findings would imply that all galaxies are moving away from each other.

Without introducing general relativity (four dimensional spacetime ) and the expansion of space in order to interpret the measurements/observations, one would have to conclude  that the earth, or our galaxy,  was the center of the universe from where a large explosion started!

Comment: Great and hoped-for answer, Anna, but I've been wondering, as part of my obsession with bouncing cosmologies (esp.'ly Nikodem J. Poplawski's "Black hole genesis", described in 2010-2020 papers that are available free on arxiv ), whether the insanely self-referential possibility described in your last paragraph could be avoided if the bouncing effects (the actual particulate motion of the OP's possibility #1) occurred on the inboard side of the event horizon of a black hole and the spatial expansion resulted, on the outboard side, from the effect of the EH's outward propagation.

Comment: @Edouard Sorry,  my expertise in general relativity models is minimal, so I cannot answer one way or the other.